# How to achieve the effect in the background using Photoshop. Tried blur without success

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I'm trying to achieve the effect seen on the "background" of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIta5.jpg) on my own photos.
So far I tried different variations of blur, in special the Shape Blur without success. At this point, I'm not even sure if this is a blur or those small crosses somehow just change the color from the picture.

Anybody has some guidance on what I should look for?

Thanks!

Comment: Blur **+** pattern overlay.

Answer (score 1):

That particular photo uses a blur as well as a subtle **pattern overlay** for the background image.

The pattern is essentially a repeated, solid, small, white rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Scott!! It was something simple that I was stuck with.

Following your advice:
1) First applied desired blur
2) Created a pattern I wanted on a separate file
3) Right clicked on Layer, than "Blending Options" and used a Pattern Overlay. It was just a matter of adjusting the opacity.

Thanks for the patience with the noob question!